# Forming a Constructor from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

From JSON, I want to request the name of a constructor and have it execute in javascript.

**json.js**

```
{
    objArray = [
        {
            "funcName":"executeMe"
        }
     ]
}
```

**page.js**

```
var newInstance = createInstanceByName(objArray[0].funcName); //"executeMe"
//Functions like: var newInstance = new lib.executeMe();
```

**lib.js** (I have no control over) looks like this:

```
(lib.executeMe = function() {
    this.initialize(img.executeMe);
}).prototype = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,200,200);
```

I was hoping I could repurpose the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) but it's important that the variable newInstance is available to me throughout page.js - it's not enough to have me pass it the context. I need the assignment to happen here.

How could createInstanceByName() work?

Answer (score 2):

```
function createInstanceByName(funcName) {
    return new lib[funcName];
}
```

---

If you need to pass arguments, then put them in an Array, and do this instead:

```
function createInstanceByName(funcName, args) {
    var inst = Object.create(lib[funcName].prototype)
    lib[funcName].apply(inst, args);
    return inst;
}
```

You could also use the `arguments` object by slicing it instead of using an Array.

The `Object.create` method isn't available in old browsers, but it can be shimmed sufficiently enough for this purpose.

Comment: Yep, this. Basically, `return new (expression.that.returns.constructor)`

Comment: Works perfectly! It was so simple...^^;;; Thank you very much